# how to reference ActionBar title View on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an `Activity` which extends the `AppCompatActivity` and uses the support `ActionBar`. Compile SDK version is 23, test devices SDK are 21-22. 
I need to get the `ActionBar`'s title `TextView`, however, the most known way of doing this

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
return (TextView) findViewById(resId);
```

doesn't work starting with API 21. Is there a way to reference the title `TextView` on Lollipop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `AppCompatActivity`, You can retrieve the `TextView` that you want indirectly, because it seems that this `TextView` has no id, like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
TextView textView = (TextView) toolbar.getChildAt(0);
```

I used the [Hierarchy Viewer](https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/index.html) tool to get the view tree. (Tool that you can find into Android Device Monitor under Hierarchy View perspective)

[image: Action bar view tree]

Comment: Great, I also found subtitle with child id 2

Answer (score 1):

Just some alternatives - you might consider defining your own custom textview to add to the toolbar if you wish to customize it - [Adding custom view to a toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907093/adding-custom-view-to-a-toolbar)

Or extending `Toolbar` -
[findViewById returns null for action_bar_title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991127/findviewbyid-returns-null-for-action-bar-title)