# Android find toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I have two modules in the app. In the second I have activity as context. The task requires toolbar animation through the second module. The problem in that I don't want to send toolbar object from 1 to 2 module, maybe there is some way to get it through the Activity obj?

Comment: you have to make `Toolbar` object to public.

Comment: Can you list some code or be more verbose?

Comment: I cannot, it's just in the paper. I have two modules in the app. In the second I have activity as context. The task requires toolbar animation through the second module. The problem in that I don't want to send toolbar object from 1 to 2 module, maybe there is some way to get it through the Activity obj?

Comment: activity.getToolbar()

Comment: @Divers, there is no such method. I can get ActionBar, but then I cannot cast it to the Toolbar and animate it as I needed.

Comment: Of course you need to create that method which returns instance of your toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not difficult at all. If you will read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32614598/5353755), you can see that toolbar has private id whitch can get be found with `getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android")`. But in some cases, when you will try to find view by this id, comes null. Then you should try to find it recursively with the second method. Hope this might help you.

```
    @Nullable public Toolbar getToolbarView(@NonNull Context context) {
        Activity activity = ((Activity) context);

        int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android");

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(resId);
        if (toolbar == null) {
            toolbar = findToolbar((ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        }
        return toolbar;
    }

    private Toolbar findToolbar(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if (view.getClass().getName().equals("android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar")
                    || view.getClass().getName().equals("android.widget.Toolbar")) {
                return (Toolbar) view;
            } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                return findToolbar((ViewGroup) view);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```